# How to call a JavaScript function that is inside a "define" - anonymous method

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, js-amd, esri-javascript-api

How to call a function which is defined inside an anonymous function but both in the same JS file. Here is my code snippet. How to call `_testMethodInside()` from `testMethodOutside()`?

```
// Line 1 to 13 is an existing code from ESRI API
    define([
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dojo/_base/html"
    ], function (
        declare,
        html
    ) {
        return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
            _testMethodInside: function () {
                return 'success';
            }
        });
    });

//Call above using this function
    function testMethodOutside(){
        //How to call _testMethodInside() function from here
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to achieve such a thing ?

Comment: @BooBerr'ita, Line 1 to 13 is an existing code from ESRI API. I want to call that method using my `testMethodOutside()`

Comment: This is called [AMD format](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) and a popular way to define modules. You can use them with `require`, and you should have a module loader library in place that declares `define` and `require`.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the [Dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/declare.html) documentation. The `define` block defines a module. You did not specify the module id (which would either be passed explicitly or inferred from the file name), so I will proceed as if the module is named `my/Example`.

```
require(['my/Example'], function(Example) {
   var example = new Example();
   example._testMethodInside(); // here is where you call _testMethodInside
}
```

The key thing is that because the module is loaded asynchronously, the only place you can safely call it from is the callback function you pass into [(AMD) `require`](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/require).

Answer (score 2):

With esri's Web app builder you'd usually either :

1) Have all your code inside the define/require
2) Separate it into two modules

That's just how the design of the flow is supposed to go, for example :

file1.js :

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/html"
], function (
    declare,
    html
) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        _testMethodInside: function () {
            return 'success';
        }
    });
});
```

file2.js :

```
  require([
        './file1'
  ], function (File1) {

      File1._testMethodInside();
  })
```

Also, method names starting with an underline is a common design choice to designate private methods, so _testMethodInside should only really be called by file1

Answer (score 0):

If it should be just a common function for the `_testMethodInside` method and `testMethodOutside` function, consider the following:

```
function sharedFunction() {
    return 'success';
}

function testMethodOutside() {
    sharedFunction();
}

define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/html"
], function (declare, html) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        _testMethodInside: sharedFunction
    });
});
```